# I always get an error when executing any apt-get

Tags: apt

Update: Couldn't fix it, ended up reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04.

Basicially, I installed a .deb of `libssl1.0.0_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` because I thought that I didn't have libssl 1.0.2-d on my Ubuntu install. However, that was not the case - I did actually have it installed, and now whenever I run any apt-get commands, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2) but 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libssl1.0.0 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0:i386 (!= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1) but 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2 is installed
 libssl1.0.0:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0 (!= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2) but 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

then when I run apt-get -f install I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libgssglue1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0.0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl1.0.0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,081 kB of archives.
After this operation, 54.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 216023 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl1.0.0_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2) over (1.0.2d-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libssl1.0.0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libssl1.0.0:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Bad pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I run sudo dpkg --configure -a I get the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.0.0:amd64 (--configure):
package libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:i386 is at a different version (1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2)
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
package libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is at a different version (1.0.2d-0ubuntu1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xrdp:
xrdp depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0); however:
Package libssl1.0.0:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package xrdp (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing
libssl1.0.0:amd64
libssl1.0.0:i386
xrdp
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I would really prefer to not have to reinstall Ubuntu...

```
user@MSI-Server-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove libssl1.0.0:amd64
[sudo] password for user:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
crda : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
heirloom-mailx : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libcurl3 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not going to be installed
libdns100 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libfreerdp-core1.1 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libfreerdp-crypto1.1 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not going to be installed
libpython2.7-stdlib : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not going to be installed
libpython3.4-minimal : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
libpython3.5-minimal : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not going to be installed
libsasl2-modules : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libsnmp30 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libspice-client-glib-2.0-8 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libssh-4 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
libtorrent-rasterbar8 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
libwinpr-rpc0.1 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libwinpr-sspi0.1 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
libwinpr-utils0.1 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
openssh-client : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
openssh-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
openssl : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not going to be installed
ppp : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
python-cryptography : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not going to be installed
python3-cryptography : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not going to be installed
sbsigntool : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
tcpdump : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
transmission-gtk : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
wget : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
wpasupplicant : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
xrdp : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
zfs-fuse : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


user@ServerUbuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2) but 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libssl1.0.0 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0:i386 (!= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1) but 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2 is installed
 libssl1.0.0:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0 (!= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2) but 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

user@ServerUbuntu:~$ sudo apt-get remove xrdp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2) but 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libssl1.0.0 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0:i386 (!= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1) but 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
 libssl1.0.0:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0 (!= 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2) but 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


user@ServerUbuntu:~$ apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0
libssl1.0.0:
  Installed: 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.0.2d-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove  libssl1.0.0_1.0.* &&  sudo apt-get autoremove &&  sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get update

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libssl1.0.0_1.0.*
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libssl1.0.0_1.0.*'

Comment: what about sudo apt-get autoremove libssl1.0.0:amd64

Comment: if `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade` still shows that the package `xrdp` is being held, try `sudo apt-get remove xrdp` then `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: What shows `apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0` and do you need the newer version you manually installed or is reverting to the original version also ok?

Comment: I edited all of those commands into the main post. Nothing is working so far. I really don't get why this isn't working - I've overwritten automatically installed debs with manually installed ones before with no issues whatsoever.